# Horizontal Deceleration for Projectile up an Inclined Plane

Tags: projectile

Consider a projectile launched **up** an inclined plane from its bottom most point. We can resolve 'g' into two components- one along the incline (decreasing the velocity component along the plane) and the other perpendicular to the plane (decreasing velocity component perpendicular to plane). What happens if the component of velocity along the plane becomes zero before velocity perpendicular to plane is zero? As velocity component along the slope is still decreasing,  what will be the nature of the subsequent motion? What will be time of flight of the projectile?

Comment: *"What happens if the component of velocity along the plane becomes zero before velocity perpendicular to plane is zero?"* How can that happen?

Comment: I feel like you are mixing the notion of a free-body “projectile” that is launched and is thereafter inertial, being acted on only by a vertical gravity force (assuming we have excluded drag.)  But once you introduce the “ramp” to the exercise, you now have a body moving up the ramp, and not an inertial “projectile” in the traditional sense.  You are trying to create a model of 3D motion while the inclined plane by definition constrains your model to motion in two dimensions…  or actually just one if the motion is aligned with the slope of the ramp.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the velocity is along the inclined plane, do it will sty so for ever till it is zero. Only the component of g in direction of the plain decelerates  the object, the force perpendicular gives you the friction wich also goes in direction of the plane.